# Writing equations below each other and using overset

Tags: overset

I want to have equations below each other and want to verify the equations by using `\overset`. I am using:

```
\begin{align*} 
3 &= 3\\
\overset{\text{...}}{&=}
\end{align*}
```

But now i don't have the equations below each other because the `&=` command is not working anymore.
Any clues?

Thank you!

Comment: what is purpose of `overset`? the way how you use them is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do, but the result is not really pretty, so I add a couple of suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The following works
\begin{align*}
3 &\overset{\hphantom{\text{Chebyshev}}}{=} 3\\
  &\overset{\text{Chebyshev}}{=} 1+2
\end{align*}
but this is much better, in my opinion
\begin{align*}
3 &= 3\\
  &= 1+2 &&\text{(Chebyshev)}
\end{align*}
If less space is wanted, then you can do like this
\begin{alignat*}{2}
3 &= 3\\
  &= 1+2 &\qquad&\text{(Chebyshev)}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
3 &= 3\\
& \phantom{} \overset{a}{=}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Alternate

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
3  &= 3\\
   &= b \quad \text{(Cauchy-Darboux)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is almost working but he then puts "a" below the equation so if i have a longer term like Tschebyscheff then the "T" is below the equation but not the equation itself.

Comment: OK. I would not use an `\overset` construct then. See an alternate construct below.